# Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "some prop" because it is not an "own property" of its parent

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

model of mongo:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const  ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    Pid:Number,
    Pname:String,
    Price: Number,
    Pdesc: String,
    Picname: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('product',ProductSchema )
```

the controller of products:

```
const express = require('express');
const Product = require('../models/products');
module.exports = {
ShowProduct:(req, res, next)=>{
    Product.find().then((products)=>{
        console.log(products);
        res.render('products', {layout: 'index', listProd:products});
    });
}
```

this is the products.hbs:

```
<div class="row">
  {{#each products}}
<div class="col-3" id={{this.Pid}}>
    <h1>Pname:{{this.Pname}}</h1>
    <div>Price:{{this.Price}}</div>
        <div>Pdesc:{{this.Pdesc}}</div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

in the browser i dont see the product
i see the count fo the product
becuse **each**.

what need to fix that??

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. As I understood it's connected with extention .hbs of your handlebars files. All you need to do is:

1. `npm install @handlebars/allow-prototype-access`
2. Add
   `const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')` to your entire point
3. Do not forget to add handlebars option!
   `const hbs = exphbs.create({ defaultLayout: 'main',  extname: 'hbs', handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars) });`